# WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EmbeddedCacheManager] with qualifiers [@Default]

Tags: dependency-injection, persistence, jboss7.x, cdi

I am getting the exception:

```
WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [EmbeddedCacheManager] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[parameter 1] of [constructor] @Inject public org.jboss.jdf.example.ticketmonster.service.SeatAllocationService(EmbeddedCacheManager)].
```

Does anyone have some tip? I have already confirmed that beans.xml is in src\main\webapp\WEB-INF and I am not publishing more than one jar. It's only one project.

```java
@Inject public SeatAllocationService(EmbeddedCacheManager manager) { 
    Configuration allocation = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .transaction()
        .transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL) 
        .transactionManagerLookup(new JBossTransactionManagerLookup()) 
        .lockingMode(LockingMode.PESSIMISTIC) 
        .loaders()
        .addFileCacheStore()
        .purgeOnStartup(true) 
        .build(); 
    manager.defineConfiguration(ALLOCATIONS, allocation); 
    this.cache = manager.getCache(ALLOCATIONS); 
}
```

POM snippet:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    ...
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-infinispan</artifactId>
    ...
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    ...
    <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Post code. The exception is very straightforward, it can't find what you are trying to inject.

Comment: Karl Kildén, thanks for your reply.

Comment: There is a warning "No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]" in the line bellow:
[code]
@Inject
public SeatAllocationService(EmbeddedCacheManager manager) {
 Configuration allocation = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.transaction().transactionMode(TransactionMode.TRANSACTIONAL)
.transactionManagerLookup(new JBossTransactionManagerLookup())
.lockingMode(LockingMode.PESSIMISTIC)
.loaders().addFileCacheStore().purgeOnStartup(true)
.build();
 manager.defineConfiguration(ALLOCATIONS, allocation);
 this.cache = manager.getCache(ALLOCATIONS);
}

Comment: In pom I have <dependencyManagement> ...  <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-infinispan</artifactId> and in <dependencies> <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>.
P.S. Sorry for the format: I didn't find how to post code source in better format.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is this is an Infinispan class and you don't have Infinispan on the classpath.

Comment: LightGuard, thank you for replying. I don't think this is the problem because I have the jar in the project library (.../.m2/repository/org/infinispan/infinispan-core/5.1.2.FINAL/infinispan-core-5.1.2.FINAL-sources.jar). Do you know if I have to set something else?

Comment: That's just the source jar. Unless you've modified the jboss-structure xml file to include infinispan, or you're bundling the compiled jar in your war, it's not in there.

Comment: LightGuard, thanks a lot. Could you give me some tips how to set Infinispan on jboss-deployment-structure.xml?  I am trying to discover from https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Class+Loading+in+AS7 but I couldn't yet.

Comment: I am really stuck to use InfiniSpan.
In jboss-deployment-structure I tryed fix by add this line:
<module name="org.infinispan" export="true" services="import"/>
In (jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\org\infinispan\main\module.xml) there are:'code'
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.infinispan">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="infinispan-core-5.1.2.FINAL.jar"/>'code'
In standalone-ha.xml there are:
'code'<extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups"/>'code'

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Getting+Started+Guide+-+JBoss+AS+7 ?